# Confused on weak/weak-* continuity/compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-topology

I have only recently been introduced to the notions of weak and weak-* topologies. I know the definition of both as well as an idea of what they represent.

It is clear through Banach-Alaoglu and Helly where

Banach Alaoglu states $\overline{B}^{*}_{1}$ is weak$-*$ compact where $\overline{B}^{*}_{1}$ is the closed unit ball in the dual of normed space $X$.

while Helly goes further that if $X$ is also separable then  $\overline{B}^{*}_{1}$ is weak$-*$ sequentially compact.

Taking both theorems into account, it is clear that weak$-*$ sequential compactness is not equivalent to weak$-*$ compactness

But I thought $X$ was not metrizable only in the weak topology, nothing was said about the weak$-*$ topology.

Further, are weak$-*$ sequential continuity and weak$-*$ continuity equivalent since we are no longer in metric spaces? As well as, are weak sequential continuity and weak continuity equivalent? Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: The statements of those theorems are wrong in several ways. B-A says that if $B$ is the closed unit ball of $X^*$ then $B$ is weak-$*$ compact; Helly says $B$ is weak-$*$ sequentially compact if $X$ is separable..

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question.

Comment: "But I thought $X$ was not metrizable only in the weak topology, nothing was said about the weak−$*$ topology." something not being said does not mean it's not true - there's not enough time or space to say everything.

Comment: Some facts: (1) If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then $X^*$ is not metrizable in the weak-* topology. (2) $\bar{B}_1^*$ is metrizable in the weak-* topology if and only if $X$ is separable.

Comment: Is weak sequential continuity equivalent to weak continuity? And weak$-*$ sequential continuity equivalent to weak$-*$ continuity?